# Should I use use .htaccess to secure Wordpress, or can I use the virtual host config file?

Tags: security, apache2

I`m using apache2 on ubuntu 11. I want to secure my wordpress site with .htaccess rules, but I understand that it is preferable to put the rules in the apache config file (httpd.conf).

If I understand correctly, the virtual site config file (under /etc/apache2/sites-available) is the config file for my wordpress, and not the main apache config.

I want to put Mod_rewrite rules on my site, but when I put it in the config file of the virtual host, apache won't start (file to read the rules).

So, do I have to use .htaccess, or can I use the virtual host config file.

(this is what I want to accomplish: http://journalxtra.com/websiteadvice/wordpress-security-hardening-htaccess-rules-4025/)

Comment: Stack overflow is probably a better place to get support on editing Apache config files.

Comment: This question should be moved to stackoverflow, wordpress, servers or any other more related site for this question. Even if using ubuntu the question is more for another more related site than askubuntu.

Comment: Maybe this might have been offtopic 9 years ago, but it isn't really now - Wordpress on Ubuntu is different enough to a "normal" installation that SatckOverflow won't be a lot of help.  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#3-configure-apache-for-wordpress is a start, but only a start.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, though it is technically "preferable" to put rule sin your apache config file, with something like a WordPress site, you're better off just using a `.htaccess` file, not least because almost everyone else who is hosting wordpress is doing it on a commercial web host where they don't have access to their Apache config files, so all the guidance out there assumes you're editing a `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

You should never put any site specific configuration in `httpd.conf` - use the site config file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` instead.

If Apache complains you did something wrong. Most statements you can put into a `.htaccess` file need to go into a  section when you put them into the site config file - it's common error to forget this.

If you can't figure it out ourself please post the site config file that causes the trouble and the error messages you get when you try to start Apache.